# web service tutorial sample on weblogic --> 404

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, maven

I have followed the web service tutorial sample and deployed on weblogic. But when I type the url, it shows 404. Am I have anything wrong or missing??
My path is http://localhost:7001/aeon_mobileapps_java_ws/UserService/users

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>My Jersey Application</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MyJerseyApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyJerseyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<library-ref>
    <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.1</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.9</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

[the url path and my project structure screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDdZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

404 error occur because of page not found or bad url. you are using jersey rest services, so you need to use path mapping of controller and method. you need to use `@Path` annotation before class and method.

you can find below sample code:

```
@Path("/test")  
public class Test{  

@GET  
@Path("/{text}")  
public Response getText(@PathParam("text") String text) {  
    String output = text;  
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();  
}
```

so with out check your code can not give correct answer, i just say only probable reasons of the error.

Comment: package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   }  
}